# Create bash script to start server and mongodb with one click

Tags: bash, mongodb

I want to run those commands in order to start a mongodb service and then run a GoLang server which connects to it.

```
echo "Starting PROGRAMATA"

echo "Starting mongoDB"
mongod
echo "mongoDB started"


echo "Starting server"
cd ~/Workspaces/GoLang/src/schedule_calculator
go run back-end/BasicWebServer/*.go
echo "Server started"

echo "Open browser to 127.0.0.1:8080
```

However once the mongodb starts the server does not start. I think it is because the mongodb starts running in the same process.

How do I make this work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should start your mongod processes with the `--fork` flag (see documentation here : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#start-mongod-as-a-daemon).

I use a similar script to start a replica set locally, and the mongod part is as follows (3 different configuration files) :

```
#/!bin/bash$

mongod -f /path/to/config/primary.conf --fork
mongod -f /path/to/config/secondary.conf --fork
mongod -f /path/to/config/arbiter.conf --fork
```

If you want to check that your mongod are running, try to connect to them (...) or use :

```
ps aux | grep mongod
```

Have fun !